# Metadata fails to download in FORCE.COM Eclipse IDE due to exceeding 600MB limit

Tags: force.com, metadata

I am attempting to download my Salesforce Sandbox into the FORCE.COM Eclipse IDE, but it fails after about 30 minutes and gives the error message:

LIMIT_EXCEEDED: The retrieved zip file exceeded the limit of 629145600 bytes.  Total bytes retrieved: 629224683 (Failed)

This error happens even if I just try to download a single 500 byte class.

I expect that the problem may be that I have several large 3rd party applications installed including Financial Force and CPQ, and that the IDE is downloading a read only copy of them for reference.  I really need to get this org downloaded so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Metadata API has a limit of 400MB](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm).

I think I encountered this and the only workaround I found was by splitting the ORG up into projects and downloading them seperately.  One thought would be try removing the documents (if you can) and see if that reduces the file size.

Comment: My download seems to stop at 600MB and not 400MB.

What documents are you referring to that need to be deleted and how can I delete them?  Right now I am downloading from a sandbox so I can delete anything safely.  I just want to get the org in Eclipse so that I can start development.